# How can I get the number of instances of a tag element with "id='foo'" using Watir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

How can I get the number of instances of a tag element with `id='foo'` using Watir?

I have this:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.a(:id => 'foo')
```

How then do I get the number of instances and access via an index, like this:

```
b.a(:id => 'foo', :index => $i) #Here, $i is a variable in a loop
```

In pseudocode I'm essentially trying to do this:

```
num = "number of a tags with id foo"
while $i less than num do
    put b.a(:id => 'foo', :index => $i).text into an array
end
```

I know how to do everything above EXCEPT finding `num`.

Comment: Is it just `.length`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know how many matches there are, you need to get an element collection (not just an element). A collection is retrieved by pluralizing the element method - ie `as`.

```
b.as(:id => 'foo')
#=> <Watir::AnchorCollection>
```

From the collection, you can use `length` (or `count`) to find the number of instances:

```
b.as(:id => 'foo').length
```

Note that the element collection is Enumerable. This means you do not need to use a `while` loop and manual track the current index and total elements. For example, using `each`, you can simply write:

```
b.as(:id => 'foo').each do |a|
  puts a.text
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work for you:

```
arr = Array.new
b.as(:id => 'foo').each { |a| arr.push a}
```